# Component hiding and showing

Tags: javascript, reactjs, object

I have a component, and inside that component I have 2 dropdown input.

The choices in the first dropdown is being fed by with an object during componentDidMount. It's working properly and here is the sample object(Lets call it Object1:

Note here is the sample code

```
{ 
 Id: 1
 Title: Country1
 Region: NA
},
{ 
 Id: 2
 Title: Country2
 Region: SA
}
```

And here is the sample code(Note I am only storing ID in my database):

```
<option value={this.state.Object1[key].ID}>
                      {this.state.Object1[key].Title}
                    </option>
```

Now my problem is what I wanted to do is I want to hide the 2nd if the Region that they selected or save is "NA". Also take note the App is where I store the Id they saved.

This is the what I tried so far. Since the Id is being fed to the component, it seems that the "this.props.id" is undefined yet during the loading of component

```
<div
                className="col"
                hidden={
                  this.state.Object1[this.props.ID]
                    .OU === "NA"
                    ? false
                    : true
                }
```

I also tried this but somehow the classname "col-hidden" is stuck and not changing even I selected a non "NA" region

```
{this.props.ID && (
            <div
              className={
                "col " +
                (this.state.Object1[
                  this.props.ID
                ].OU ===
                  "NA")
                  ? "col-hidden"
                  : "test"
              }
            >
              <label htmlFor="Region">Region</label>
              <select
                id="SubRegion"
                name="SubRegion"
                onChange={this.props.onChange}
                className="custom-select"
                required
              >
                <option value="sample">Sample</option>
              </select>
            </div>
          )}
```

Comment: By the key is just from the key when I populate the dropdown choices using map

{Object.keys(this.state.Object1).map(key => (

Answer (score 1):

Render the div only after `ID` props is received:

```
{
  this.props.ID &&
  <div className="col" hidden={this.state.Object1[this.props.ID].OU === 'NA'}></div>
}
```

Ternary operator is not required in this case as you're just returning the boolean value. The above condition will return true if it strictly equals to `NA`, else it will return false.

---

Additionally, I would just use the className to switch the show/hide:

```
{
  this.props.ID &&
  <div 
    className={
    'col ' + (this.state.Object1[this.props.ID].OU === 'NA')
     ? 'hidden' : 'shown'
  }>
  </div>
}
```

---

As per your comment, you should use the state for maintaining the value props. Props are readonly. So, onChange handler should update some state and value should be responding to that.

```
// initialize state in the constructor:
this.state = {
  myId: 0
}

// update the state in your onChange handler
this.setState({myId: this.state.Object1[this.props.ID].OU === 'NA' ? '1' : '2'})

// now in the value props
value={this.state.myId}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is one more way of hiding it. Once you get the value from the dropdown, you can call one function say onInputChange() and create a state variable called { isDisplay: false }

```
onInputChange() {
 if(this.state.Object1[this.props.ID].OU === 'NA') {
  this.setState({ isDisplay: true }) 
 }
}
```

So now where you want to show or hide that value use the state value. i.e.,

```
{this.state.isDisplay ? 
  <div className='col'>
   //which ever value you want to show
  </div>
  : null
}
```

This will show the value which is in  only if isDisplay is equal to true.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for contributing. Where should I use the onInputChange? Note that I am passing Id to my component using props

Comment: Hi, You can use that onInputChange when you call onChange in the select tag or you can replace the content which is there in onInputChange to the props.onChange function which you have already called.

Answer (score 0):

Upon checking I just need to create function for onChange of my dropdown

```
onst hideRegionFunction = e => {
  this.props.onChange(e);
  let self = this;
  let Region = this.state.Region;

  Region["isHidden"] = false;

  self.state.Object1.forEach(element => {
    if (element.ID == e.target.value && element.OU == "NA") {

      Region["isHidden"] = true;
    }
  });

  this.setState({ Region });
```

And using that to hide my 2nd column. My initial problem was the number is not the same as index